# Improving the performance of searching Microsoft Word using office-js

Tags: javascript, office-js

I have the following code to search a paragraph in a document for some text and if any occurrences are found then select the first one.

```
function navigateToWord(paragraphId, text){
    Word.run(function (context) {

        var ps = context.document.body.paragraphs;
        context.load(ps, 'items');

        return context.sync()
            .then(function (){
                let p = ps.items[paragraphId];

                let results = p.search(text);
                context.load(results, 'items');

                return context.sync().then(function(){
                    if(results.items.length>0){
                        results.items[0].select();
                    }
                }).then(context.sync);
            });

    });
}
```

This works but it is very slow, especially on larger documents on Word Online (Word Desktop performs slightly better). How can I improve it?

I plan on invoking this code quite a few times (*with different input parameters*), is there a way to cache the loaded properties, so that the second time I invoke the same code, I don't have to wait as long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading much more than you need. First a minor point: specifying 'items' in the load command is unnecessary. 'items' are automatically loaded when you have a context.load for a collection object. So `context.load(ps, 'items');` is equivalent to `context.load(ps);` More importantly, by not specifying any other properties, load defaults to loading all the properties including the text, so all of the text of all of your paragraphs is going over the wire. It is a best practice to specify the properties that you need in the load command. In your case, however, you don't need any, so you should put a dummy string as the second parameter to load. This blocks loading of any properties. The following code works and should be much faster, especially in Word Online:

```
function navigateToWord(paragraphId, text){
  Word.run(function (context) {

    var ps = context.document.body.paragraphs;
    context.load(ps, 'no-properties-needed');

    return context.sync()
        .then(function (){
            let p = ps.items[paragraphId];

            let results = p.search(text);
            context.load(results, 'no-properties-needed');

            return context.sync().then(function(){
                if(results.items.length>0){
                    results.items[0].select();
                }
            }).then(context.sync);
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You really helped me - it is a lot faster now.